# How do I display a Java HttpPost object as a string?

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am creating an `HttpPost` object in Android to communicate with a server operated by a client.  Unfortunately the server isn't providing either of us with very useful error messages; I would like to see the content of the `HttpPost` object as a string so I can send it to our client and he can compare it with what he's expecting.

How can I convert an HttpPost object into a string that reflects how it would look as it arrived at the server?

Comment: Which language your server code is on? Is it Servlet (or) PHP (or) Something else?

Comment: .NET, but I don't have control over the server.

Answer (score 2):

Should use it after execute

```
public static String httpPostToString(HttpPost httppost) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("\nRequestLine:");
    sb.append(httppost.getRequestLine().toString());

    int i = 0;
    for(Header header : httppost.getAllHeaders()){
      if(i == 0){
          sb.append("\nHeader:");
      }
        i++;
        for(HeaderElement element : header.getElements()){
            for(NameValuePair nvp :element.getParameters()){
                sb.append(nvp.getName());
                sb.append("=");
                sb.append(nvp.getValue());
                sb.append(";");
            }
        }
    }
    HttpEntity entity = httppost.getEntity();

    String content = "";
    if(entity != null){
        try {

            content = IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    sb.append("\nContent:");
    sb.append(content);


    return sb.toString();
}
```

[snippet](https://gist.github.com/proofy/264e957ba0cc190ee8d3)

Comment: Thanks for the great example! Just using it in my code, I've realised *commons-io* doesn't close the IS, thus it might be worse closing a Java InputStream using the try-with-resources construct:
```try(InputStream entityContent = entity.getContent()) {
    content = IOUtils.toString(entityContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }```

See: 
* https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html
* http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstream.html

Answer (score 0):

I usually do post in this way (The server answer is a JSON object) :

```
    try {
        postJSON.put("param1", param1);
        postJSON.put("param2",param2);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String result = JSONGetHTTP.postData(url);
    if (result != null) {
        try {

            JSONObject jObjec = new JSONObject(result);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error setting data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

And postData is:

```
public static String postData(String url, JSONObject obj) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = null;
    try {
        HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 30000);
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("POST_DATA", "error in httpConnection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
        //Header here   httppost.setHeader();
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());

        httppost.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // // Do something with response...
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // convert response to string
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    } finally {

        try {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    if (result != null) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            JSONObject jObjec = new JSONObject(result);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well i actually did `HTTP-Post` using `NameValuePair`...... I am showing the code which i use to do an `HTTP-Post` and then **converting the Response** into a `String`

**See the below Method code:**

```
public String postData(String url, String xmlQuery) {



final String urlStr = url;
final String xmlStr = xmlQuery;
final StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();


Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);


    try {

         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlStr));

         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

         Log.d("Vivek", response.toString());

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream i = entity.getContent();

        Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String s = null;


        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

            Log.d("YumZing", s);
            sb.append(s);
        }


        Log.d("Check Now",sb+"");




        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }

        });

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method "+sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not having any trouble converting the response; it's the call I'm interested in, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @AndrewWyld don't mind, but i think you missed the portion where i said that i am doing an `HTTP Post using NamePairValue`